# Is Transit visa required for Kuwait Airport self-transfer?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, kuwait, self-transfer

I am an Indian passport holder. I have a flight from Rome to Kuwait (WizzAir) and then Kuwait to Chennai (AirIndia) with a layover of 5-6 hours. Both the legs were booked as separate tickets and hence separate airlines and PNRs. Do I need a transit visa to collect baggage and then check-in again with AirIndia? (or) Can I rely on [NAS Kuwait](https://www.nas.aero/PassengerServices.aspx) to do that?

Comment: any update regarding this question. did u made the travel ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need a transit visa to collect baggage and then check-in again with AirIndia?

Yes. A self transfer is the same as two individual flights that just happen on the same day. You will need proper entry documentation to enter Kuwait.

> Can I rely on NAS Kuwait to do that?

If you are planning to book a "meet & assist" service your best bet is to ask the provider directly. You can check https://pearlassist.com/kuwait-kwi-intl-kuwait-kuwait for "standard" services but it's not clear whether they would support "self-transfer" since that includes moving luggage (which transit typically doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need a transit visa to collect baggage and then check-in again
> with AirIndia?

There is no concept of transit visa for Indian passport holders in Kuwait. You will need a valid entry visa (and only business visas are being issued currently). You will have to collect bags yourself and check in again at Departure level.

> Can I rely on NAS Kuwait to do that?

No, they wont assist with this.