# Transit Visa for self-transfer in Abu Dhabi (AUH)

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, transit-visas, auh, self-transfer

I have a flight(WizzAir) from Rome to Abu Dhabi on 6th August which reached at 8 PM (local time) in Abu Dhabi and then a flight (AirArabia) from Abu Dhabi to Chennai (India) at 11 PM (local time). These 2 flights are booked separately and hence don't share a PNR. I will need to do a self-transfer at the airport, collect baggage and check-in again. Can I get a visa-on-arrival to do that? I have a valid Tourist (C-Type) Schengen Visa.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of your [earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/181837/32790)?

Comment: Looks like the OP has changed connection from Kuwait to Abhu Dabi. Won't help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I get a visa-on-arrival to do that?

I don't believe. India is not a "visa on arrival country"

> I have a valid Tourist (C-Type) Schengen Visa.

You would qualify if you had a Schengen Residence permit. I don't think a tourist Visa will help here. See https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/do-you-need-an-entry-permit-or-a-visa-to-enter-the-uae/visa-on-arrival

3 hours also seem awfully short for a self connection, especially since you have to clear immigration and customs.

Your best bet may be to connect somewhere in the Schengen area. Currently the only two flights from Schengen to Chennai are operated by Lufthansa and Air France. You have more options going to Delhi or Mumbai first. Yes, this will be more expensive, but the routing is safer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The other option I am considering is booking Etihad Airways from Rome to Abu Dhabi which reaches at 6:25 PM. They mention that provide UAE Transit visas as they are part of the UAE airways. Would that work?

The other Schengen connection to Delhi, Mumbai seems more costly. Would want to explore other options before going for this one.

Comment: Transit and visa rules are notoriously complicated and I strongly encourage to research this yourself. We can help here to some extent but there is absolutely no guarantee you get a correct or complete answer. A good resource is https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm but that doesn't cover self transfer. It would be much safer for you to shell the extra money for an "easy" connection.

Answer (score 1):

For Indian passport holders, you can get visa on arrival in UAE ONLY if you have EU residency. Schengen Type C does not qualify for VOA.

However, if you have have a tourist visa from USA or UK, then you will be eligible for UAE VOA.

Check if you are eligible for transit visa at AUH https://www.abudhabiairport.ae/en/passenger-guide/transit/things-to-do/more-than-4-hours